# OOP - are there any disadvantages in using static methods?

Tags: c++, oop, opencv

I want to design a project which is build for video processing and I plan to use openCV.
I want to add an Utils class which contains only static functions and its purpose is to incorporate various functions which depends only on its parameters and do various processing steps, for example `Utils::processFramHsvSpace(cv::Mat inputFrame)` which processes a `cv::Mat` and returns a certain features extracted from HSV space.

Is there any disadvantages for this type of approach in terms of memory usage? Instead of this, should I add a method to the main class and use the class member variables?

Comment: Why not create them in a namespace?

Comment: Why not global functions? No disadvantages in terms of memory usage. But you are using classes for something they're not designed for. Global functions (either in a namespace or not) is better.

Comment: If you have only functions and no state and no clear responsibilities the type is supposed to handle, a class isn't the best design ... also it's soooo Java. ;) Make them free functions in a named namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pop quiz!

What can you read better:

```
Vector::length(v);

v.length();

length(v);
```

As thokra puts it, C++ is not Java. You have the option of methods on the class, static methods and free form functions. Use them. If you need to group them put them into a namespace. This has the advantage, that you can use a `using` clause where the namespace association is obvious.

Comment: If this is a pop quiz, you forgot the `None of the above` option ;)